# Recursive sequence generation

Tags: .net, recursion, f#

I'm trying to generate a sequence of slices by recursively reading data from my data source.

```
let rec read stream startFrom (conn : IEventStoreConnection) = 
    seq {
        let size = 10000
        let slice = conn.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(stream, startFrom, size, true).Result

        Console.WriteLine("Events in slice: " + slice.Events.Count().ToString())

        if (slice.IsEndOfStream) then
           yield slice
        else
           yield! read stream (startFrom + 1 * size) conn 
    }

let slices = read "stream-name" 0 conn

Console.WriteLine("TOTAL slices in sequence: " + (Seq.length slices).ToString());
```

I was expecting the sequence to contain three items, yet it only seems to return just one, the last one.

```
Events in slice: 10000
Events in slice: 10000
Events in slice: 4501
TOTAL slices in sequence: 1
```

Why isn't the result of my recursive call being yielded as well? A scoping thing?

Comment: SO think about what happens - if you are not at the end of the stream, you recurse until you are at the end.  Only the end of the stream actually returns something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As John already told you, you have to yield the other slices too:

```
let rec read stream startFrom (conn : IEventStoreConnection) = 
    seq {
        let size = 10000
        let slice = conn.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(stream, startFrom, size, true).Result

        Console.WriteLine("Events in slice: " + slice.Events.Count().ToString())

        if (slice.IsEndOfStream) 
        then
           yield slice
        else
           yield slice // here
           yield! read stream (startFrom + 1 * size) conn 
    }
```

I think you could clean this a bit up using inner functions:

```
let read (conn : IEventStoreConnection) stream startFrom = 
    let size = 10000
    let rec loop startFrom =
       seq {
           let slice = conn.ReadStreamEventsForwardAsync(stream, startFrom, size, true).Result

           Console.WriteLine("Events in slice: " + slice.Events.Count().ToString())

           if (slice.IsEndOfStream) 
           then
              yield slice
           else
              yield slice // here
              yield! loop (startFrom + 1 * size)
       }
    loop startFrom
```

Answer (score 1):

For an alternate take on this (which doesn't attempt to encapsulate the sliced loading in this manner, opting to manage that aspect separately in order to parallelize the 'playing' of the events, be theta with NES or GES), see the [loading/deserialization loop in FunDomain](https://github.com/bartelink/FunDomain/blob/58a6be34203d462383fbdc7c18c79ab3eb73e584/FunDomain/CommandHandler.fs#L7-L19).

NB all the code in FunDomain is really just [FsUno.Prod](http://thinkbeforecoding.github.io/FsUno.Prod/) refactored a lot.